Have I missed something?
I'm just writing some quick number guessing game code, but I keep running into the "Expected Unqualified id" error.
I've checked all the semicolons, but maybe I've missed something?
Here's my code:
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>  // srand

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;

int main(void) {
/* code goes here */
srand (time(NULL));
int number = rand() % 100+1;
int guess = 0;

cout << number << endl; /* debug */

do {
/* code goes here */
cout << "Guess a number between 1 and 100: ";
cin >> guess;

if ( guess > number ) { cout << "Too high, try again. \n" << endl;}
else if ( guess < number ) { cout << "Too low, try again. \n" << endl; }
else { cout << "That's right! \n" << endl; }

exit(0);
} // fi
while  ((number));! std:: = guess);
return (0); }
// main }`

and here's the error text:
ERROR!
/tmp/3NFruHJf2U.cpp: In function 'int main()':
/tmp/3NFruHJf2U.cpp:27:27: error: expected unqualified-id before '=' token
27 | while  ((number));! std:: = guess);
  |                           ^


What do you expect std:: to do? It's just a notion of standard library namespace instead of a function.

Please try to find an entry level book in the list.

FYI, nothing gets executed after exit(0)'.  Since this is in main(), you can return from main without the exit.

Your program processes the guess, then exits the program.  No repeats in the do-while loop, nothing.  Just exits to the operating system.  One pass only.

Maybe your while expression should be (number != guess).  Just guessing.  This doesn't matter because the exit(0) will cause the program to exit before the while statement is processed.

Recommend you edit the title to something that includes the words "Guessing Game."

Unrelated: Change stdlib.h to cstdlib

Unrelated: you should indent your code properly, so it is readable. Unreadable code is hard to work with, even more for beginners.

The loop ends with while  ((number));, which is valid but wrong. Then you have the statement ! std:: = guess);, which is a complete mystery.

Probably you want to use:
while(number != guess);

and remove exit(0)
